# Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a Asp.net Core Angular 2 app using the SPA template provided by VS2017. Everything works fine locally. But when published to Azure as a web application the following error occurs:

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Attempt to connect
>   to Node timed out after 60000ms.)

I checked the stdout file and I also see the following error prior to the above:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to bind to
>   http://localhost:19013 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -4090
>   EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available'.

I am not finding much online also, there is no code change from my end and its just the default template.

Comment: I test with verson **15.3.5** of the VS2017, it works correctly on my side both on local and Azure. If you didn't use the latest version of VS2017, please have a try to update to the latest version and If create a new WebApp App is possible, please have a try to create a new one and try again.

Comment: I am running the same version. Also I have just deployed the default template . Without any code change or config changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like for an app service, we need to explicitly add node version on the app services in the app settings.

Doing it resolved the issue.

Comment: Would you share your app settings / app services sample?

Comment: Brian, I added WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION with a value 8.7.0

Comment: Wasted days due to this and finally you save my time. 
here is the detail how to do this 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/

Comment: there should be an existing `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` appsetting when the website is created?

Comment: I spent a couple of days with multiple VS templates until I saw your question and answer here. Lifesaver!

Comment: @watashiSHUN Creating the website doesn't add `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` by default. I have tried it couple of times.